# MVC and jQuery template?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, templates

I have a controller that returns a custom model back to its view. Within this model is a collection of products and prices which are rendered in the view, alongside other information that is required by the page.

However, I'd like to use jQuery templates to allow an AJAX update of those products and prices.

I guess its not possible to render the template with initial values so how do I return a model that includes both "static" information (ie wont chnage on the page) and also information that I do want to include in the template as it will change dependent on input of the user?

Comment: Appologies, but I am having trouble parsing the last paragraph.  Can you say more about what you are trying to accomplish?  Is it that you want to render the initial HTML on the server (using normal View techniques, razor, etc) and that you want to be able to refresh that HTML via Ajax+templates later?  Or is it that you want to always generate the html via a template and you are asking how to pass the model to your javascript for that first render?

Answer (score 0):

You can load content via jquery from your control like this:

Jquery:

```
function lastPostFunc(movies) {

            $.each(movies, function(i) {

                var milli = this.ReleaseDate.replace(/\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\//, '$1');
                var d = new Date(parseInt(milli));

                $("#Movie_list").append("<tr class=wrdLatest id=" + this.Id + "><td>" + this.Id + "</td><td>" + this.Title + "</td><td>" + d + "</td><td>"
         + this.Genre + "</td><td>" + this.Price + "</td><td>" + this.Rating + "</td></tr>");
            });

        }
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + 100 > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

                var name = id; //$(".wrdLatest:last").attr("id");
                var value = { skip: name };
                $.post("/Movies/GetMovies/", value, lastPostFunc, "json");
                id += 50;
            }
        });
```

Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult GetMovies(string skip)
        {
            // caching the categories 

            int idtoSkip = Convert.ToInt32(skip);
            var movies = from m in _db.Movie
                         where m.Id > idtoSkip & m.Id < idtoSkip + 50
                         select m;
            return Json(movies);
        }
```

Comment: I want to make use of jQuery Templates though instead of emitting my own html.

Comment: See: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx

Comment: Actually, I think I've found the answer here:http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/render-your-model-with-client-side-jquery-templates-instead-of-asp-net-mvc-partial-views/